# Postman - Mac - v 7.15.0 - Redirect from using production endpoint to using test endpoint

Tags: c#, mocking, postman, endpoint

I'm not sure I'm wording this correctly, so patience appreciated...

- I have a simple web app that is hosted on Azure.
- In the C# code, I have 2 endpoints a production endpoint and a mock data endpoint.
- Whenever I want to test it I have to republish the project commenting out the production endpoint and uncommenting the mock data endpoint.
- Is there a way I can? (proxy - if that is the right term) the traffic?

Basically, my goal is to redirect traffic from going to https://some-production-endpoint.json and instead send it to the mock data that I've created https://e8199548-bla-bla.mock.pstmn.io --- without having to publish new code to Azure or deal with some config file.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Probably you could use Postman Environment variables. You simply add environment variable, e.g. {{host}}, into your URL instead of actual endpoints. Then create 2 environments: Prod and Mock. Add your actual endpoints into {{host}} variables for each environment. So you can easily switch between Prod and Mock, without proxying your request and still have the only request collection in Postman.

Comment: ok, thanks - don't have privs to star that up as answered yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Postman Environment variables.

You simply add environment variable, e.g. `{{host}}`, into your URL instead of actual endpoints.

Then create 2 environments: `Prod` and `Mock`. Add your actual endpoints into `{{host}}` variables for each environment.

So you can easily switch between `Prod` and `Mock`, without proxying your request and still have the only request collection in Postman.

More info about environments can be found [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables/).